# About Android dialogs

Tags: java, android, progressdialog

I use example from http://startandroid.ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/128-urok-67-dialogi-progressdialog.html

We have two buttons. 
onClick first button - show some progress dialog. 
 
onClick second button - show some progress dialog. 
 

If I click fast on first button after that on second button then it is showing two progress dialogs. How to disable this posibility?(Is it good to disable this two buttons when is clicked one of them, or disable LinearLayout, ...)

strings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string name="dflt">Обычный</string>
<string name="horiz">Горизонтальный</string>
<string name="app_name">ProgressDialog</string>
</resources>
```

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical">
<Button
 android:id="@+id/btnDefault"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="@string/dflt"
 android:onClick="onclick">
</Button>
<Button
 android:id="@+id/btnHoriz"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="@string/horiz"
 android:onClick="onclick">
</Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package ru.startandroid.develop.p0671progressdialog;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  ProgressDialog pd;
  Handler h;

  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

  }

  public void onclick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btnDefault:
      pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
      pd.setTitle("Title");
      pd.setMessage("Message");
      // добавляем кнопку
      pd.setButton(Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK", new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        }
      });
      pd.show();
      break;
    case R.id.btnHoriz:
      pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
      pd.setTitle("Title");
      pd.setMessage("Message");
      // меняем стиль на индикатор
      pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
      // устанавливаем максимум
      pd.setMax(2148);
      // включаем анимацию ожидания
      pd.setIndeterminate(true);
      pd.show();
      h = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
          // выключаем анимацию ожидания
          pd.setIndeterminate(false);
          if (pd.getProgress() < pd.getMax()) {
            // увеличиваем значения индикаторов
            pd.incrementProgressBy(50);
            pd.incrementSecondaryProgressBy(75);
            h.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 100);
          } else {
            pd.dismiss();
          }
        }
      };
      h.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 2000);
      break;
    default:
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of disabling views just create a boolean variable that you set to true when a dialog is clicked. In your onClick function you can check if there is already an active dialog. Then you can add an onDismissListener to your dialogs and reset the boolean variable.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying when clicking another button, you want the current progress dialog to go away before showing the new one? I think you would need to dismiss the dialog if it is showing then with a simple check in your `onClick()`

```
  public void onclick(View v) {
     if (pd != null) {
        pd.dismiss();
     }
     switch (v.getId()) {
     case R.id.btnDefault:
     ....
```